# Not enough free disk space on /boot

Tags: boot, 20.04

Not able to install updates for Ubuntu, or even remove older packages from /boot

Many answers suggested good solutions, but again I am not able to even remove older packages from /boot.

[Not enough free disk space when upgrading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298487/not-enough-free-disk-space-when-upgrading)

[Unable to update ubuntu applications because there is not enough space on /boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524081/unable-to-update-ubuntu-applications-because-there-is-not-enough-space-on-boot)

I am stuck in a loop here, my /boot size is 256M

`df -h` output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           1.6G  2.2M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5   82G   39G   39G  50% /
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p6  256M  186M   50M  79% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1   96M   31M   66M  32% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G  120K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda2        67G   32K   64G   1% /media/nmt/3bf914c7-c1b2-47f0-9820-42dd7eb06059
```

`dpkg -l | grep linux-image` output:

```
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-21-generic              5.19.0-21.21                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-23-generic              5.19.0-23.24                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-26-generic              5.19.0-26.27                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-28-generic              5.19.0-28.29                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-29-generic              5.19.0-29.30                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-31-generic              5.19.0-31.32                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-35-generic              5.19.0-35.36                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-38-generic              5.19.0-38.39                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic              5.19.0-40.41                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.19.0-41-generic              5.19.0-41.42                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
iF  linux-image-5.19.0-42-generic              5.19.0-42.43                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04              5.19.0.42.38                             amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

`uname -r` output:

```
5.19.0-42-generic
```

`sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-5.19.0-21-generic` output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'linux-image-5.19.0-21-generic' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 165 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-5.19.0-42-generic (5.19.0-42.43) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.19.0-42-generic (5.19.0-42.43) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-42-generic
zstd: error 25 : Write error : No space left on device (cannot write compressed block) 
E: mkinitramfs failure zstd -q -1 -T0 25
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-42-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.19.0-42-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.19.0-42-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.19.0-42-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Update:**

`ls -lah /boot` output:

```
total 178M
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Jun  3 11:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root 4.0K Nov 15  2022 ..
-rw-------  1 root root 6.2M Mar 23 23:36 System.map-5.19.0-40-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6.2M Apr 17 17:56 System.map-5.19.0-41-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 6.2M Apr 18 20:50 System.map-5.19.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 264K Mar 23 23:36 config-5.19.0-40-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 264K Apr 17 17:56 config-5.19.0-41-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 264K Apr 18 20:50 config-5.19.0-42-generic
drwx------  4 root root 1.0K Jan  1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K May 18 06:58 grub
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   28 May 18 06:57 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.19.0-42-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  68M May  5 06:47 initrd.img-5.19.0-41-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  68M May 18 06:58 initrd.img-5.19.0-42-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   28 May 17 08:04 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.19.0-41-generic
drwx------  2 root root  16K Nov 15  2022 lost+found
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 179K Feb  6  2022 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K Feb  6  2022 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 181K Feb  6  2022 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   25 May 17 08:04 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.19.0-42-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  12M Apr 17 20:55 vmlinuz-5.19.0-41-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  12M Apr 18 20:55 vmlinuz-5.19.0-42-generic
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   25 May 17 08:04 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.19.0-41-generic
```

Comment: "*I am not able to even remove older packages from /boot*" Correct: `rc` means that kernel has *already* been removed. That's merely of index of known packages, not a list what's actually on your system. Please edit your question to show the complete output of `ls -lah /boot`. Check that output for old, orphaned files that can be safely removed.

Comment: @user535733 I updated my question.

Comment: Your boot-partition is way too small.

Comment: Please update your question to include output of `lsblk`.

Comment: I struggled with fixing the issue since I found that I did more damage than I expected, and reinstalled ubuntu leaving more space for swap and boot this time, I was not aware of this configuration when I first installed it. thanks for the answers. the question can be closed.

Comment: That's not how AskUbuntu works. You can flag you own question, if you wish. But it's better if you answer your own question to help future users with a similar problem.